# Is there a quick way to return a string without its escape sequences in Python?

Tags: python, string, escaping, string-literals

I want to be able to tell if a string foo == 'some string'. This works most of the time. I realize, however, that there may be times when foo contains escape sequences such as '\n' or '\t', and I want to account for this. Is there anything quick, or built-in to Python 2.7 that will help me with this? Or will I have to essentially go through all escape sequences and make sure none of them are infesting my string foo?

Here's an example if you're still unsure:

```
foo = '\tZebra'
```

So when I print foo it appears as

```
    Zebra
```

and I can't easily be sure that there are no escape sequences such as '\t' when testing foo against a string literal:

```
foo == 'Zebra'
```

returns False.

I thought of is using these lines:

```
if 'Zebra' in foo:
    bar()
```

but this accounts for MORE than just escape sequences of Python. For example:

```
foo = 'ttZebra'
if 'Zebra' in foo:
    print 'bar'
```

this will indeed print 'bar'.

So, how can I quickly remove all escape sequences from a string before I use it? Also, if this helps, I know that none of my strings will contain spaces because they all come from a .split() list.

---

**Answer:**

I tried using .strip(), and that helped, but my program still wasn't working. It turns out all of my files have [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)s. However, the BOM sequence is always the same so it is very easy to deal with. I still use .strip() to account for all escape sequences.

Comment: maybe try using `strip()` ... `foo = foo.strip()`

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about stripping any sequences from the beginning and end of the string, then use `strip()`

```
>>> foo = '\tZebra'
>>> foo.strip()
>>> 'Zebra'
```

If you want it to strip in the middle of the string as well, you can do the following

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('[\x00-\x1F\x7F]', '', '\tZebra\tZebra')
'ZebraZebra'
```

The above regular expression strips out all [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character).

Comment: It turns out that I think the problem I'm dealing with is actually the [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which is basically adding '\xeb\xbb\xbf' to the start of all of my text streams. I now use strip as well, but the UTF-8 BOM thing is easy to deal with because its always at the start and is always the same sequence of escapes or whatever they are, so I can just tell my program to ignore them.

Comment: How are you opening the text file? The UTF8 BOM should be automatically stripped out.